# How to shift pandas rows based on multiple loc parameters?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame consists of several columns which has information about sequence number based on system_name:

```sql
|id|time               |system_name|status    |sequence 
---+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------
001|2022-06-01 10:00:12|A          |RUNNING   |1        
002|2022-06-01 10:01:02|B          |RUNNING   |1
003|2022-06-01 10:01:45|A          |DONE      |2
004|2022-06-01 10:01:52|B          |DONE      |2
005|2022-06-01 10:02:00|C          |RUNNING   |1
006|2022-06-01 10:02:02|B          |ERROR     |3
007|2022-06-01 10:02:13|A          |IDLE      |3
008|2022-06-01 10:01:02|C          |DONE      |2
```

However I want to join condition based on previous sequence like below

```sql
 id|time               |system_name|status    |sequence |previous_stat|last_time          |
---+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
003|2022-06-01 10:01:45|A          |DONE      |2        |RUNNING      |2022-06-01 10:00:12|
004|2022-06-01 10:01:52|B          |DONE      |2        |RUNNING      |2022-06-01 10:01:02|
005|2022-06-01 10:02:00|C          |RUNNING   |1        |nan          |nta                |
006|2022-06-01 10:02:02|B          |ERROR     |3        |DONE         |2022-06-01 10:01:52|     
007|2022-06-01 10:02:13|A          |IDLE      |3        |DONE         |2022-06-01 10:01:45|
008|2022-06-01 10:01:02|C          |DONE      |2        |RUNNING      |2022-06-01 10:02:00|
```

I have tried to using `.loc` function like below:

```py
df['previous_stat'] = df['status'].loc[(df['sequence']==df['sequence'].values-1)&(df['system_name']=df['system_name'])]
```

But couldn't get the right previous stat and last time.
any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `groupby` with `shift` then `join` back and `dropna`

```
out = df.join(df.groupby('system_name').shift()[['status','time']].add_prefix('pervious_')).dropna()
```